Pandas list of list column to Python list
I want to create a list from a Pandas column formatted like so:
data = {
    'col': [
        '[[a, b, c], [a,b]]',
        '[[a, b], [c]]',
        '[[x]]'
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

The result should be something like this:
python_list = [[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c']],
 [['x']]]

So basically a List[List[List[Str]]]. Doing it with a non-nested list would be something simple like df.str.split().tolist(), but I have no clue how to do it for this case. Thanks a lot in advance!

Your column contains strings of (possibly nested) lists, not actual lists. Post us an actual executable code and data (MCVE).

Welp that's the issue here. The column is formatted like a string of nested lists, but without the '.

But the column is still a string? If not, why are you accessing it with df.str...? We need you to post actual executable code and data (MCVE/[MCVE]), like I asked. That's why SO requires you to post MCVE.

there's no easy way to do this other than just get your hands dirty and work out the recursive call in each cell.

Your input isn't JSON because the objects a,b,c aren't strings 'a','b','c'. Seems you want to recursively flatten nested lists, and quote each object.

You can try applying a custom function like this:
def parse_list(s: str):
    q = []
    for c in s:
        if c == '[':    # indicate beginning of a list
            q.append(c)
        elif c == ']':  # indicate end of a list
            e = []      # create that list
            while True:    
                b = q.pop()  # pop the queue until we see the beginning  
                if b == '[':
                    break
                e.append(b)  # append the element to the list
            q.append(e[::-1]) # reverse the list and add back to queue
        elif c == ',' or c == ' ': # these does nothing
            # do nothing
            continue
        else:
            q.append(c)            # element, may need to modify this a bit
                
    return q[0]

out = df['col'].apply(parse_list).to_list()

Output:
[[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']], [['a', 'b'], ['c']], [['x']]]

Note: this only works for singleton strings (a,b,c,...). One needs to modify it to work with general strings, where one needs to work out the role of ,

Nice one ;) It can also be updated to handle escape characters if needed.

You are reinventing the wheel; the input is string, looks like it was JSON? Then just use json.loads()

@smci '[a,b,c]' is NOT a JSON string; '["a","b","c"]' is.

@QuangHoang: My mistake. a,b,c can't be names of constants or variables. So what does the OP want to do? Recurse through an arbitrarily nested list, quoting all names as string?

If your strings are simple (no escaped quotes/brackets), then you could use a simple regex and ast.literal_eval:
from ast import literal_eval
import re

out = [literal_eval(re.sub(r' *([^][ ,]+) *', r'"\1"', s))
       for s in df['col']]

Output:
[[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b']],
 [['a', 'b'], ['c']],
 [['x']]]

